# How can I validate a field to specific numbers?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have two fields on a form, one has a can have a value of either 0 or 10 or more, the other can have a value of 0 or 100 or more. How would I mark that up to validate that what is entered in those fields (if anything) adheres to these guidelines. Fields are below:

```
<div class="fb-input-number">
          <input name="unassembled" type="text" id="unassembled" autocomplete="off"     value=""  data-hint="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item8" class="fb-item fb-50-item-column" style="padding-bottom: 5px; ">
        <div class="fb-grouplabel">
          <label id="item8_label_0" style="display: inline; ">
            Number of <font color="#FF0000" >Assembled</font> Hygiene Kits (Min. 10) @2.50/ea.
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-input-number">
          <input name="assembled" type="text" id="assembled" autocomplete="off" value="" data-hint="" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out these links [validation1](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/30/10-examples-of-basic-input-validation-in-javascript/) and [validation2](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-sample-registration-form-validation.php)

from your question it is difficult to understand what type of validation you want
Thanks

Comment: Thanks @NetStarter, that's close, and I think there is something I can do with that. Appreciate the direction, definitely more helpful than the ass douches that decide to just vote my question down rather than actually help someone.

Comment: welcome @JeremyChambers and dnt be so rude buddy its a part of the SO.we learn things by all of this,thanks and please dnt forget to mark the answers as accepted if its solve your problem it will benefit in your future post